# Font rendering issue with imagefttext in PHP

Tags: php, fonts, rendering

I am running into a weird font rendering issue when writing text over images using `imagefttext()`.

`$img = imagecreatefromjpeg( $canvas_image_path );
imagettftext( $img, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $font_color, $font_path, $text );`

I have a tool which selects a background image (different sizes - JPEGs (.jpg)) to work on and then write the text over it which comes from an WYSIWYG editor.

1. Using Bodoni-italic font, for certain image sizes the rendering of `i` is weird.
2. Spacing looks weird after `T`

[image: screenshot]

It works absolutely fine for images that are small like `320 x 240` or big like `1536 x 2048` but for other sizes in between that range, `i` is written as shown in screenshot.

Now the fact that it does show up correctly for certain image sizes rule out the possibility of something being wrong with the font file itself. The only suspect I see here is the image size but I am not sure how to debug the situation from here & find a fix for it.

Any idea on where I should be looking or what can possibly cause this?

Comment: do some basic debugging. try dumping out the entire alphabet (upper + lower case) and see if it happens for any other letters. try different fonts, then vary the image size in stages and see if it occurs at particular sizes.

Comment: @MarcB It only happens for `i` with Bodoni-italic. Other characters or a different font work fine. And I roughly have the range of image sizes with which it happens, what's next I should be looking at?

Comment: wonder if it's a bug in gd, or your font file's munged somehow. got any other systems you could try this on, with a different gd version?

Comment: @MarcB Unfortunately all systems that I have access to, are running GD v2.1.0 compatible and if font file was munged somehow, it shouldn't be able to render `i` at all, but here the issue somehow seems related to image size.